# HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'application/form-data' not supported spring-boot

Tags: angular, spring-boot, file-upload, jhipster

After configuring these files **application.yml, application-dev.yml, application-prod.yml** on Jhipster:

```
spring:
    application:
        name: xxx
    http:
        multipart:
            enabled: true
            max-file-size: 200MB
            file-size-threshold: 2MB
            max-request-size: 215MB
```

I got the error:

```
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping.handleNoMatch(RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping.java:221)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.lookupHandlerMethod(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:374)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.getHandlerInternal(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:314)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.getHandlerInternal(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:61)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMapping.getHandler(AbstractHandlerMapping.java:352)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.getHandler(DispatcherServlet.java:1160)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:940)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
```

This is an example of my controller:

```
    package com.xxx.xxx.web.rest;
    
    import com.xxx.xxx.service.FileUploadDownloadService;
    import org.slf4j.Logger;
    import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
    import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;
    import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
    import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
    import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
    import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;
    
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.net.MalformedURLException;
    
    @RestController
    @RequestMapping("/api")
    public class FileUploadDownloadController {
    
        private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(FileUploadDownloadController.class);
    
        private final FileUploadDownloadService service;
    
        public FileUploadDownloadController(FileUploadDownloadService fileUploadDownloadService) {
            this.service = fileUploadDownloadService;
        }
    
        @PostMapping(value = "/file/uploadFile", consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
        public UploadFileResponse uploadFile(
            @RequestParam("filename") String name,
            @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {
            String fileName = service.uploadFile(file);
    
            return new UploadFileResponse(fileName);
        }
    }
```

This is my Angular service to upload:

```
    import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
    import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';
    import {Headers, Http, RequestOptions} from '@angular/http';
    
    @Injectable()
    export class FileService {
    
        private resourceUrl = 'api/file';
    
        constructor(private http: Http) {
        }
    
        uploadSingleFile(file: File): Observable<any> {
            const formData: FormData = new FormData();
            formData.append('file', file);
    
            const headers = new Headers();
            headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/form-data');
    
            const options = new RequestOptions({ headers });
    
            console.log(formData);
            return this.http.post(`${this.resourceUrl}/uploadFile`, formData, options );
        }
    }
```

My version of spring-boot is 1.5.4.RELEASE,
Java version 1.8.0_275,
Node Version 10.17,
JHipster Version 4.6.0

I've read many posts and all of those said the same configuration that I've done (enabled multipart support), is there something that I had been misunderstood or forgotten?

Thanks for your support.

Comment: In Spring you are expecting a content-type "multipart/form-data", but you are sending a "application/form-data" from angular. Have you tried using "multipart/form-data" in Angular?

Comment: Yes, in fact, it seems that this content type doesn't exist, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types/Common_types

And reading another post, I found that it's not necessary to indicate the multipart/form-data because the browser infers the content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading some post I found that is not necessary to indicate the content type If you try to send multipart/form-data, and the content type that I was trying to send was incorrect because doesn't exist so I've removed that line:

<s>headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/form-data');</s>

So, that's. I hope that this can help someone.

Regards.